# how to kill brown driver from a node

Tags: ros, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am implementing an algorithm on icreate and i am using brown driver for this.
I have an issue that when my node finishes its task, i want brown driver binary to stop as well. Otherwise, the robot keeps going although i kill the node.
How can i kill the brown driver from a node?
Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43094/how-to-kill-brown-driver-from-a-node/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally speaking, robot control through the starting and stopping of processes is sloppy and hard to control. Is it not possible for you to just send some sort of "stop" command, instead?

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2012-09-05**:
Thanks firstly. i just wanted to somehow integrate into the launch file. It might be the driver's buffer issue as well. However, i do not have much control over the the brown driver. I was wondering how to trigger a system call from the node.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-06**:
You really shouldn't be doing this. What are you trying to do exactly?

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2012-09-10**:
Actually, the robot is doing coverage for some cells according to the algorithm and the robot does not stop somehow ! So i wanted to stop brown driver which will cause the stopping for sure. There might be some sync. issue as well.

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-04-08**:
I'm doing some work with odometry, and I reboot the driver each time I start (to zero the wheel odometry).  In all of the code I wrote, I have a shutdown command that kills all of my nodes triggered by the end-of-experiment condition, but I still need to ctrl-c kill the driver.